# sphinx search(I have a job database in sphinx and each job is related to the company.)

Tags: laravel, sphinx

I have a job database in sphinx and each job is related to the company.

I want to send job alerts to users and that count is a maximum of 10 jobs in one alert email.

I also want to restrict one single company jobs count to 3. I want to take more than 3
jobs only if I not able to find 10 jobs for alerts.

Can you please someone tell me how I can achieve this through a sphinx search?

Comment: Sounds like you can benefit from Manticore Search's (fork of Sphinx) Percolate Queries - https://play.manticoresearch.com/pq/ as it was initially designed for tasks like yours.

Comment: I did reply to this question on the SPhinx forum http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=16518 . For what it worth, dont see how Percoalte queries will help directly, as they can't implement this 3 results per company (unless under 10 results) logic. Going to be still doing the filtering in post-processing.